# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\array_except() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application, I  have an option to update user details, following is the update function in my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)

    {

        $this->validate($request, [

            'name' => 'required',

            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,

            'password' => 'same:confirm-password',

            'comp_id'=>'required',

            'roles' => 'required'

        ]);

    

        $input = $request->all();

        if(!empty($input['password'])){ 

            $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);

        }else{

            $input = array_except($input,array('password'));    

        }

    

        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->update($input);

        DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id',$id)->delete();

    

        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

    

        return redirect()->route('customers.index')

                        ->with('success','Customer updated successfully');

    }
```

But when I try to execute the above function am getting an error saying,

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\array_except()
```

I used the exac same code in the other update functions as well, but they worked without an issue..

Comment: Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: if you are using latest laravel version >=5.7 then https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-except

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include `use Illuminate\Support\Arr;` in your code and change:

```
$input = array_except($input,array('password'));
```

to

```
$input = Arr::except($input,array('password'));
```

`array_except()` is deprecated in versions greater than 5.8 for laravel

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$array = ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100];

$filtered = Arr::except($array, ['price']);
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-array-except

**Solution 2**:

Starting **Laravel 6**, most of the `str_` & `array_` helpers funcs are accessible ONLY by the new **laravel/helpers composer package**, if you don't have this package you'll get this sort of error.

Install helpers' package:

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

and

```
composer dump-autoload
```